# Error when sqooping data to Vertica with column name as 'From','To'

Tags: sqoop, vertica

I am trying to sqoop data to Vertioca to a table which has Column named 'From','To', because of which I am getting erorr as VJDBC ERROR: Syntax error at or near "To" . Any alternative to this if we cannot change the column name in DB

Comment: surround the keyword `To` with double quotes: `"To"`

Comment: Double quotes worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @marcothesane in the comment, Adding double quotes resolved my problem.